# Identifying the Sharepoint site linked to a Team created through the Microsoft Graph api

Tags: php, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am currently building a system that sets up a team for a 'project', and want to automate the upload of necessary documents. The files tab in the team is linked to a sharepoint site which i can get the link to manually through Teams, but i cant find any form of link to the site, or ID in the api response. I have looked through the documentation and cant find anything, any help would be appreciated.

I have tried using the team ID as the site ID, aswell as any other ID or path, in a 'get site' request. i have used the data returned from the teamsAsyncOperation in the same manner. Which all return {"code": "itemNotFound", "message": "Item not found"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files tab in the team's channel is linked to a [driveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0) through [filesFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) relationship.

To get the metadata for the location where [the files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-filesfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of a channel are stored you need to use `teamId` and `channelId`.

```
GET /teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/filesFolder
```

The response should contain `id` of `driveItem` and `parentReference` with `driveId`.

Now you have `driveId` and `driveItemId`, so you can upload documents using the following [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Answer (score 1):

You can access a group team site via /sites/root
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#access-a-group-team-site

Try something like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupid>/sites/root?$select=webUrl
```

You can reuse the Group Id from the Create Team request. That id should be listed in the Content-Location field of the Response Headers. You can retrieve that via a [slice](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#slice) function.

```
slice(outputs('Send_an_HTTP_request_-_Create_Team')['Headers']['Content-Location'], 8, -2)
```

[image]